# How to make a radio app keep playing in the background of my Android App

Tags: android, background, audio-player, internet-radio

Am still new to android, but i followed a tutorial online in developing a radio Application, now this is the problem am encountering, i want this radio to keep playing, so that the app user can keep using the app or other application while the radio plays in the background. The radio stops playing when the user leave the streaming page.

```
  private void startPlaying() {
  buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
  buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);
  player.start();


   }


  private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
  player = new MediaPlayer();
  try {
  player.setDataSource(" radio URL");

  player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
  player.start();


  }
  });
  player.prepareAsync();
  buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
  buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);


  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }

  player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

  public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
  playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
  Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
  }
  });
  }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
 super.onPause();
 if (player.isPlaying()) {
 player.pause();
 buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
 buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
 }

 }
```

Comment: Use service to play radio app in background.

Comment: thank you for your response kyogs, but how can i implement this service to what i have

Comment: Please use "code formatting". Even Eclipse will do this automatically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

refer this [link](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/307-light-racer-20-days-61-64-completion)

```
Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
    startService(svc);



public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.idil);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response kyogs, am grateful. i will try this and as soon as it works for me i will accept your answer.thanks once again

Comment: the R.raw.idil generates an error, but its a live radio am playing in my app that i want to keep playing

Comment: this code is for playing music from raw folder.u dont need this one.remove this line and implement your logic as u need .